# Why has my JAVA SDK no javac binary?

Tags: java, javac

I am using jdk-8u5-windows-i586 on Windows  ?

```
C:\prog\j\j-8u5-w-i586\bin> dir java*.exe

25.06.2014  14:20            15.784 java-rmi.exe
25.06.2014  14:20           176.040 java.exe
25.06.2014  14:20            68.008 javacpl.exe
25.06.2014  14:20           176.040 javaw.exe
25.06.2014  14:20           264.616 javaws.exe
```

**ANSWER** 
(i want to give here as the question is flagged)
I have checked that. I have downloaded the SDK jdk-8u5-windows-i586.exe from oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/…. When I give custom folder (C:\prog\java\jdk-8u5-windows-i586) during setup, the setup copies files also into C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_05\bin (Which seem weird)

```
C:\PF(x86)\J\j1.8.0_05\bin> dir java*.exe
 Verzeichnis von C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_05\bin
25.06.2014  14:18            15.752 java-rmi.exe
25.06.2014  14:18           176.008 java.exe
25.06.2014  14:18            15.752 javac.exe
25.06.2014  14:18            15.752 javadoc.exe
25.06.2014  14:18            69.000 javafxpackager.exe
25.06.2014  14:18            15.752 javah.exe
25.06.2014  14:18            15.752 javap.exe
25.06.2014  14:18           176.008 javaw.exe
25.06.2014  14:18           264.584 javaws.exe
```

Comment: are you sure you downloaded jdk and not jre ?

Comment: Is there a "/jre" folder in "C:/prog/j/j-8u5-w-i586"?

Comment: This is great, thanks for all the answers. I may messed it up, don't really know what. Flag it to remove. stackoverflow is great !

Comment: I have checked that. I have downloaded the SDK jdk-8u5-windows-i586.exe from http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html. When I give custom folder (C:\prog\java\jdk-8u5-windows-i586) during setup, the setup copies files also into C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_05\bin

Answer (score 1):

As @Jigar Joshi pointed out you installed a JRE and is in the wrong dir (the name of the folder is `jdk-8u5-windows-i586`).

So you should go here in order to install it: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html

Just to clarify, compare the two different installations that I have and the binaries in each:

## JRE 8

**Directory of C:\Program Files\Java\jre8\bin**

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jre8\bin\dir *.exe
30/04/2014  11:13 PM            34,216 jabswitch.exe
30/04/2014  11:13 PM            15,784 java-rmi.exe
30/04/2014  11:13 PM           190,888 java.exe
30/04/2014  11:13 PM            76,200 javacpl.exe
30/04/2014  11:13 PM           191,400 javaw.exe
30/04/2014  11:13 PM           313,256 javaws.exe
30/04/2014  11:13 PM            15,784 jjs.exe
30/04/2014  11:13 PM            68,008 jp2launcher.exe
30/04/2014  11:13 PM            16,296 keytool.exe
30/04/2014  11:13 PM            16,296 kinit.exe
30/04/2014  11:13 PM            16,296 klist.exe
30/04/2014  11:13 PM            16,296 ktab.exe
30/04/2014  11:13 PM            16,296 orbd.exe
30/04/2014  11:13 PM            16,296 pack200.exe
30/04/2014  11:13 PM            16,808 policytool.exe
30/04/2014  11:13 PM            15,784 rmid.exe
30/04/2014  11:13 PM            16,808 rmiregistry.exe
30/04/2014  11:13 PM            16,808 servertool.exe
30/04/2014  11:13 PM            64,424 ssvagent.exe
30/04/2014  11:13 PM            16,296 tnameserv.exe
30/04/2014  11:13 PM           196,008 unpack200.exe
```

## JDK 8

**Directory of C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_05\bin**

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_05\bin\dir *.exe
30/04/2014  11:11 PM            16,264 appletviewer.exe
30/04/2014  11:11 PM            16,264 extcheck.exe
30/04/2014  11:11 PM            16,264 idlj.exe
30/04/2014  11:11 PM            34,184 jabswitch.exe
30/04/2014  11:11 PM            15,752 jar.exe
30/04/2014  11:11 PM            16,264 jarsigner.exe
30/04/2014  11:11 PM            15,752 java-rmi.exe
30/04/2014  11:11 PM           190,856 java.exe
30/04/2014  11:11 PM            15,752 javac.exe
30/04/2014  11:11 PM            16,264 javadoc.exe
30/04/2014  11:11 PM            80,776 javafxpackager.exe
30/04/2014  11:11 PM            15,752 javah.exe
30/04/2014  11:11 PM            15,752 javap.exe
30/04/2014  11:11 PM           191,368 javaw.exe
30/04/2014  11:11 PM           313,224 javaws.exe
30/04/2014  11:11 PM            15,752 jcmd.exe
30/04/2014  11:11 PM            16,776 jconsole.exe
30/04/2014  11:11 PM            16,264 jdb.exe
30/04/2014  11:11 PM            15,752 jdeps.exe
30/04/2014  11:11 PM            15,752 jhat.exe
30/04/2014  11:11 PM            16,264 jinfo.exe
30/04/2014  11:11 PM            15,752 jjs.exe
30/04/2014  11:11 PM            16,264 jmap.exe
30/04/2014  11:11 PM           318,856 jmc.exe
30/04/2014  11:11 PM            15,752 jps.exe
30/04/2014  11:11 PM            16,776 jrunscript.exe
30/04/2014  11:11 PM            16,264 jsadebugd.exe
30/04/2014  11:11 PM            16,264 jstack.exe
30/04/2014  11:11 PM            15,752 jstat.exe
30/04/2014  11:11 PM            15,752 jstatd.exe
30/04/2014  11:11 PM           195,976 jvisualvm.exe
30/04/2014  11:11 PM            16,264 keytool.exe
30/04/2014  11:11 PM            16,264 kinit.exe
30/04/2014  11:11 PM            16,264 klist.exe
30/04/2014  11:11 PM            16,264 ktab.exe
30/04/2014  11:11 PM            16,776 native2ascii.exe
30/04/2014  11:11 PM            16,264 orbd.exe
30/04/2014  11:11 PM            16,264 pack200.exe
30/04/2014  11:11 PM            16,776 policytool.exe
30/04/2014  11:11 PM            15,752 rmic.exe
30/04/2014  11:11 PM            15,752 rmid.exe
30/04/2014  11:11 PM            16,776 rmiregistry.exe
30/04/2014  11:11 PM            16,264 schemagen.exe
30/04/2014  11:11 PM            16,264 serialver.exe
30/04/2014  11:11 PM            16,776 servertool.exe
30/04/2014  11:11 PM            16,264 tnameserv.exe
30/04/2014  11:11 PM           195,976 unpack200.exe
30/04/2014  11:11 PM            15,752 wsgen.exe
30/04/2014  11:11 PM            16,264 wsimport.exe
30/04/2014  11:11 PM            16,264 xjc.exe
```

Comment: Could it be that he shortened the names of the directories in the path?

Comment: @clcto, that wouldn't explain the missing files. I really believe that's just a JRE in that folder `C:\prog\j\j-8u5-w-i586\bin`

Answer (score 0):

You should have

```
java
javac
javadoc
javah
javap
javaws
```

Since you are missing a few of these, I suspect you have the JRE not the JDK.